# Can any one suggest to correct below array comprehension in Julia

Tags: julia

I am getting error while running below code.

```
powers = [value^2 for value in 1:8 if value%2==0 else 10]
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What does the else clause mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for

```
julia> [value % 2 == 0 ? value^2 : 10 for value in 1:8]
8-element Array{Int64,1}:
 10
  4
 10
 16
 10
 36
 10
 64
```